# Proper project creation procedure for Ruby on Rails in Xcode 10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, project, setup-project

When I try to start a new project, i go to external build system, indicate the path to the ruby installation, and then get a project, but from here I am completely lost.

I am learning to code in ruby language using the rails framework.  My Professor has recommended we use visual studio Coding IDE, but I think I could benefit greatly from the experience in Xcode I would get if I could do my programming in xcode.

```
$ rails generate scaffold Book title:string description:text 
isbn:number published_date:datetime     '


class createDemousers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
def change
create_table :demo_users do |t|
t.string :last_name
t.integer :age

t.timestamps
end
end
end

AND

"<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>DEMO</TITILE>
<%= STYLESHEET_LINK_TAG 'APPLICATION', media: 'all', 'data- 
turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track':
'reload' %>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>my Demo App</h1>
</div>
<%=yield%>
</body>
</html>"
```

I build the files, and can alter an rtf file into a .rb(ruby) file, but I don't know which ones and how to alter them so that they work in a normal project on the rails framework, like they would on xcode.  I am confused as to what "target" means as well.  Anybody experienced in using outside configurations in XCODE please help me!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using something other than Xcode. Xcode is meant for developing iOS and Mac apps in Swift or Objective-C, not for Ruby on Rails. The only thing Xcode can really give you for Ruby programming is syntax highlighting, which you can get in a text editor.

Use a text editor to work with Rails. Text Mate 2 is a free editor that comes with a Ruby on Rails bundle to make working with Rails easier. Visual Studio Code is another free editor that has extensions you can install for working with Rails. Sublime Text and BBEdit are also popular Mac text editors.